# Calling a web-service via NHibernate

Tags: web-services, nhibernate

We have a webservice that is created to perform database operations. The service is created in JAVA with Hibernate.

Can we use NHibernate to access that java service in our .Net code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you kind of misunderstand what NHibernate does. It is just a library that facilitates database access. It's not because your webservice uses hibernate internally that you need NHibernate in the .net part. Actually, with a webservice, you're not really interested in the internal workings of the webservice. You're just interested in what the webservice exposes: the contract.

If you want to consume that contract in your .net code, you should be looking at a [WCF client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx)